# WPF DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate прокрутка дочерних записей

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть следующий `XAML` код:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}"
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Если IsEnabled установить в True, прокрутка для дочерних записей работать не будет  -->
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          IsEnabled="False"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Данная таблица умеет отображать дочерние записи для каждой родительской строки. Т.е. когда мы выделяем какую-нибудь из родительских строк - в качестве деталей этой строки отображаются дочерние записи. При этом, используя **колесо мыши** мы можем осуществлять прокрутку (scroll) по дочерним записям.

Суть проблемы

Как можно заметить у `DataGrid`, который отображает дочерние записи, свойство `IsEnabled` установлено в `False`, при таких настройках прокрутка по дочерним записям с помощью **колеса мыши** работает. Но как только свойство `IsEnabled` я устанавливаю в `True` прокрутка с помощью **колеса мыши** по дочерним записям работать перестает, а нужно что бы работала.

Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том что, когда курсор мыши находится над `DataGrid` с дочерними элементами и начинается прокрутка колесика мыши, то генерируется туннелируемое событие `PreviewMouseWheel` и для того чтобы таблица прокрутилась необходимо чтобы пришел ответ (пузырьковое событие - `MouseWheel`). Ответ по каким-то причинам у вас не приходит.

Решение заключается в том, чтобы перехватить событие `PreviewMouseWheel` и сгенерировать ответ событие - `MouseWheel`:

Установите "System.Windows.Interactivity v4.0 for WPF" из NuGet.
Добавьте пространство имен:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Собственно логика перехватывания и генерирования ответа при помощи Behavior:

```
public sealed class IgnoreMouseWheelBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel -= AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        var e2 = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
        e2.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;

        AssociatedObject.RaiseEvent(e2);

    }

}
```

теперь применение:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:IgnoreMouseWheelBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы помогли мне. Хотя мне до сих пор не понятно, почему по умолчанию на распространение события `PreviewMouseWheel` у дочернего `DataGrid` влияет свойство `IsEnabled`, т.е. почему когда значение свойства `true` событие не проходит, а когда значение `false` все ок. Странно как-то.

Comment: @sp7, рад что помогло. Когда IsEnabled в false, туннилируемое событие в этот датагрид не посылается, соответственно ждать ответа не приходится.

Comment: @sp7, по поводу куда пропадает событие и почему ответ не приходит сказать не могу, если кто знает то может ответить.

Comment: Наоборот, когда `IsEnabled` в `false` - все работает, а вот когда `true` проблемы. Поэтому я и говорю, что странно.